# creating objects with for loop

Tags: java, loops

I am creating objects of the class Room, but I dont want them in a list/ array. The standard method would be

```
Room room1 = new Room();
Room room2 = new Room();
Room room3 = new Room();
Room room4 = new Room();
```

etc..

since the names of the rooms matter I was thinking I could do:

```
for(int i=0; i<(whatever);i++){
Room (room + i) = new Room();
}
```

this dont work. Does anyone know if I can do this easily as I need to name them room1, room2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Simply you cannot. Variables names should be statically typed (*at least without any byte code manipulations*).

If you want to access them with your *index (i)* later, use array or ArrayList.

Comment: I upvoted you, thanx for the answer

Comment: @mynameishi Thank you Ishi :) Someone else downvoted. I don't know the reason.